# how to make account dynamic in hardhat.config.js?

Tags: hardhat, erc-721

I am building an API service so a caller can mint Polygon NFTs through API calls.

Below is my hardhat.config.js

```
/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
 require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");
 require('dotenv').config();
 require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");

const { PRIVATE_KEY } = process.env;
module.exports = {
  defaultNetwork: "PolygonMumbai",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
    },
     PolygonMumbai: {
     url: "https://rpc-mumbai.maticvigil.com",
    //  url: "https://polygon-rpc.com",
      accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY]
    }
  },
  solidity: {
    version: "0.8.17",
    settings: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200
      }
    }
  },
}
```

Currently, the private key of the account that mints the NFT is stored in the .env file that is accessed by the hardhat.config.js

I want to make the service in a way that the private key is passed in the request parameter
and the NFT is minted to that account as the owner and funder.

below is the mint function

```
async function mintNFT(contractAddress, metaDataURL) {
  const Hashi = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("Hashi")
  const [owner] = await hre.ethers.getSigners()
  const result = await Hashi.attach(contractAddress).mintNFT(owner, metaDataURL)

  console.log(result)

  return result
}
```

How do I manage to pass the private key to hardhat.config.js dynamically based on the request call?

```
 accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY]
```

Comment: Hardhat isn't meant to be used like that. It's a local development environment - not for building APIs.

Comment: Thanks .. what is another way of going about building an API service?

Comment: @rohit Sending the private key in the request seems a bad idea. Either there's a "minter" account in the backend or each request is signed by the user on the client side.